# Switch between ringer and vibrate based on schedule?

Tags: calls, profiles, automation

Certain times of the week I would like the phone to be on vibrate and other times of the week I want it to be on ringer. I would like to setup a schedule for these changes to happen automatically. Can this be done? If not natively is there an app that can do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [Locale](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.twofortyfouram.locale) (more expensive, but easier to use) or [Tasker](http://www.appbrain.com/app/net.dinglisch.android.taskerm) (less expensive, more complicated to use/more configurable).

Answer (score 1):

For a simple and free app to schedule changes ring tone/mode based on time of day and day of the week I recommend [SoundManager](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.roozen.SoundManager).

Another free app that does this is [Profile Changer](http://www.appbrain.com/app/com.cubeit.profilechanger).  I've looked at it but haven't actually used it.

For full featured automation including time based, location based, app based... I'd go with Bryan's recommendation of Tasker.